# Exercise about constraint qualifications?

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

[image]

Attempt:

a) Let $f(x)=5x-x^2$. Notice that $g_1(x)\cap f(x)=0$. Therefore if there exists a maximum of $f(x)$ it must be $\overline x=0$.

b) I think it refers to the constrait qualifications: Slatters, Zangwill, Kuhn-Tucker, Cotters and l.i..

I don't quite understand what is asked to do, Should I first substitute $\overline x=0$ in each constraint qualification and then to verify that $\exists x\in X:g_1(x)<0,\forall i\in I,\overline D=G',\overline A=G',\overline G_0=G'$ and $\{\nabla g_1(\overline x),i\in I\}$ is l.i., respectively ?

or what should I do?

c) I think the necessary conditions are this

In this case we are in $\mathbb R^2$, hence $\nabla f(\overline x)=(5\ 0)^t,\nabla g_1(\overline x)=(1 \ 0)^t$. When I solve the system to verify the existence of $u\ge 0$, I get that $u=-5$, but this is not correct.

Also I don't know where is this $T=G'$ applied? or how will I applied?

Could someone explain please??

Thank you!

Comment: I can't upload the image about necessary conditions :/

Comment: are they really necesary to mention?